# how to add wsdl web service with .xml extension in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, wsdl, web-reference

this is my web wsdl web service [url](https://www.someonline.com/msc_dev_wsdl.xml) .
so I want to add this as a web reference.They have used open source software called `soapUI.exe`. Should I have to use this or is there a way to do this.
I tried with visual studio like follow,

**solution explorer ---> References --->add service reference -->advanced ---> add web reference ---> place the url ---> press go.**

then it popup a warning window  more than 20 times  like this

[image]

I have no idea.hope your help

Comment: Not loading mentioned URL https://www.someonline.com/msc_dev_wsdl.xml

Comment: I cant give you the exact url, sorry for that